# Цикл игнорирует часть карты

Tags: java, foreach, map

Думаю, из кода всё будет понятно, но для описания:
Создал карту, внёс имена и фамилии
В методах выясняю, сколько таких же имён, которые я ищу
Почему-то цикл `foreach` игнорирует первую половину карты (выяснил, добавив вывод на экран элемента карты на каждой итерации)

---

***Почему первая половина карты игнорируется массивом?***

[Код на GitHub](https://github.com/nikitafront/java/blob/master/src/com/nikita/progs/Solution.java)

Comment: У вас не так много кода, чтобы его не добавить в вопрос. Так лучше будет, т.к. код вы потом можете удалить и вопрос потеряет смысл. Также в некоторых регионах GitHub может быть заблокирован (правительством или MircroSoft-ом из-за санкций). Выложите код текстом прямо в тело вопроса.

Comment: Вопрос решён - я добавлял значения по одинаковым ключам, из-за этого ранее созданные пары перезаписывались